# Scaling image and keeping its proportions

Tags: jquery, image, scaling

I'm working on a photo sharing site. When displaying an image in full size I want the width to be of maximum 800px, as well as the height to be of maximum 600.

The code below works for scaling, but it doesn't keep the image's proportions. I guess I could use percentage instead, but I still want the image to have these specific maximum values (h: 800, w: 600).

Is there a way of accomplishing that with jQuery?

Thanks in advance!

```
    if ($('#photo').length > 0) {
        var imgWidth = $("#photo").width();
        var imgHeight = $("#photo").height();

        if (imgWidth > 800) {
            $("#photo").width(800);
        }
        if (imgHeight > 600) {
            $("#photo").height(600);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use 
`max-width` or `max-height`

Comment: A CSS solution! I like it. Here's the relevant documentation: [max-width - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/max-width).

Comment: it can be a perfect solution.

Comment: Scaling in CSS can be a huge waste of bandwidth, making page loads really slow.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to multiply both the width and the height by the same scaling constant.

If you're limiting by the width, multiply by 800/width.

If you're limiting by the height, multiply by 600/height.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
var imgWidth = $("#photo").width();
var imgHeight = $("#photo").height();
var maxWidth = 800;
if (imgWidth > maxWidth) {
    var newWidthMultiplier = maxWidth / imgWidth;
    $("#photo").width(maxWidth);
    $("#photo").height(newWidthMultiplier * imgHeight);
}
```